# Arranging Images on Slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a presentation with 6 images on separate slides and I want to write a script to rearrange them to one slide (on a grid formation).

I have already automated grabbing the images and adding them to the slides, but I cannot figure out how to arrange then automatically.

What would be some possible ways to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident but I think you can only 'copy' an image with [insertImage(image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertimageimage)

1. Get an image
2. Copy to target slide
3. Set position [setLeft(left)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#setleftleft) [setTop(top)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#settoptop)
4. Delete original image
5. Go back to 1 to handle another 4 images